# Not getting any results back from this xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation, xml-namespaces

I have this xml output from a webservice:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <FLNewIndividualID xmlns="http://www.test.com/wsdl/TTypes">
       <ObjectType>C1</ObjectType>
       <ObjectReference>101000216193</ObjectReference>
       <ObjectReference xsi:nil="true"/>
       <ObjectReference xsi:nil="true"/>
    </FLNewIndividualID>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am trying to extract the ObjectType and the ObjectReference
so I have this XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xmlns:nsl="http://www.test.com/wsdl/TTypes"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/env:Envelope/env:Body/nsl:FLNewIndividualID">
<xsl:value-of select="ObjectType"/>-<xsl:value-of select="ObjectReference"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I just get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

as the result
If I add a blank attribute to the results xmlns=""
eg.

```
<ObjectType xmlns="">C1</ObjectType>
<ObjectReference xmlns="">101000216193</ObjectReference>
```

then it works and I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  C1-101000216193
```

Any ideas? I can't change the XML output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<FLNewIndividualID>` has a default namespace set, so its children inherit that namespace.

Try

```
<xsl:value-of select="nsl:ObjectType" />
<xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="nsl:ObjectReference" />
```

Also it would be a good idea to use `exclude-result-prefixes`.

For example like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:nsl="http://www.test.com/wsdl/TTypes"
  exclude-result-prefixes="env nsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="nsl:FLNewIndividualID">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(nsl:ObjectType, '-', nsl:ObjectReference)" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(of course this sample does not produce well-formed XML)